# What is the correct way to initialize a variable from a binary buffer?

Tags: c++, variables, memory, binary, initialization

I have often come across the situation where I receive packed binary data (i.e. where the variables are not correctly aligned) over a protocol, and the data usually comes in a std::string, a std::vector, or some other such container.

My question is what is the best practice for unpacking such data? I would normally perform something like:

```
int32_t x = *((int32_t*)charPtr);
```

or for an iterator

```
int32_t x = *((int32_t*)(&(*itt)));
```

but these really feel like a hack, and although they could be wrapped up in a template function, is there not a more direct way to tell the compiler what I want?

Comment: If there are inconsistencies in the Endian-ness between the sender/protocol and your code doing the receive processing, there are other considerations than the ones you are asking.  Other than the obvious, for example some protocols define the Endian-ness at the WORD level, but none at the DWORD level, so you might have THAT to deal with.

Comment: I'm quite sure that if you are using intX_t and you are working on a local machine (ie no endian mismatch risks) both expressions work, and do not incur in undefined behaviours, obviously before using that you should be sure that you have at least X - 1 chars after the intial one. If you already have a char pointer use the first one, otherwhise the second one or:
&myvector[x] or &mystring[x] as charPtr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct, avoiding undefined behavior, way of doing this would be:

```
int32_t x;
memcpy(&x, charPtr, sizeof(x));
```

which you can wrap in a function template:

```
template <class T,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_trivially_default_constructible<T>::value &&
        std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value, int> = 0>
T unpack(unsigned char* p) {
    T val;
    memcpy(&val, p, sizeof(val));
    return val;
}
```

Comment: That behaviour is defined if he is working on a local machine, your code will add a not needed copy overhead...

Comment: @gabry It's defined only if there is an object of type `int32_t` that exists at `charPtr`.